# Как реализовать переход в предыдущее меню

Tags: java

Подскажите как сделать, чтобы по вводу 0 возвращало на предыдущие пункты меню?

```
public void openStore()
{
    System.out.println("Вас приветствует магазин " + name + "." + "\nДля просмотра всех товаров нажмите " 
                + "1." + "\nДля просмотра корзины нажмите " + "2." 
                + "\nДля завершения нажмите " + "3.");


    int choise = sc.nextInt();
```

например, тут нужно чтоб после отображения изначальных трёх пунктов при вводе 0, возвращало к предыдущему выбору пунктов.

```
    if(choise==1)
    {
        System.out.println("1. Телевизоры");
        System.out.println("2. Стиральные машинки");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("0 - назад. Для просмотра всего ассортимента введите соответствующее число");
        choise = sc.nextInt();
        if(choise==1) //просмотр всех ТВ
        {
            for(int i=0,j=1;i<2;i++,j++)
            {
                System.out.print(j + ". ");
                System.out.println(tvs[i]); 
            }
            System.out.println("0 - назад. Чтобы добавить товар в корзину введите соответствующее число");

            choise =sc.nextInt();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обернуть меню в конструкцию `switch-case` и зациклить с условием выхода при вводе цифры 3.

```
int choice = 0;
while (choice != 3) {
    switch (choice) {
        case 0:
            System.out.println("Вас приветствует магазин..."); break;
        case 1:
            System.out.println("Товары..."); break;
        case 2:
            System.out.println("Корзина..."); break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Неверная команда"); break;
    }
    choice = sc.nextInt();
}
```